# Problem with .cod deployment to simulator

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, deployment, simulator

This is a re-post of a topic on the Blackberry Development Forums, but I wasn't getting any answers there, so I thought I would try SO.

I have an in-house library that I developed called Ichabod that is required by one of our applications, Spyder, which runs on the Blackberry 4.5.0 operating system (our original target was for 8330 devices).  I had everything working with bb-ant-tools to compile the library, which is in a separate project, and deploy it to C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.21\components\simulator.  The Spyder application debugged just fine in the eclipse plugin (I am using Galileo with the 1.1.2 version of the RIM plugin).

Today, however, I went to debug the Spyder application after making a couple of changes to the code (no code changes were made in Ichabod), and found that the application couldn't find the Ichabod module all of a sudden.  I noticed that there was now a net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\ directory in my eclipse plugins folder, so thinking that perhaps I updated the component packs without realizing it, I adjusted the target path of the Ichabod library, and rebuilt it with bb-ant-tools.  Same problem.  So, I tried removing the .cod and all associated files from both the 4.5.0.21 and 4.5.0.28 directories, recompiled the Ichabod library to deploy to both locations, and found that it works with 4.5.0.21, but not with 4.5.0.28 (it's not listed in the modules screen under Settings, either).

I have verified that the .cod file is present in the components\simulator folder, but I can't seem to figure out why the simulators don't recognize the file.

Any suggestions?

My bb-ant-tools build.xml script is attached.

Thanks,

~Scott

```
    <taskdef resource="bb-ant-defs.xml" classpath="lib/bb-ant-tools.jar" />

    <property name="jdehome" value="C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.28\components" />

    <property name="simulator" value="${jdehome}\simulator" />

    <property name="bin" value="${jdehome}\bin" />

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Builds and Deploys Project (installs to simulator)">
        <copy todir="${simulator}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="output">
                <include name="*.cod" />
                <include name="*.debug" />
                <include name="*.csl" />
                <include name="*.cso" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans the output directory">
        <delete dir="output"/>
        <mkdir dir="output"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="clean" description="Builds Project">
        <rapc jdehome="${jdehome}" 
            destdir="output" 
            output="Ichabod" 
            quiet="false">

            <jdp type="library" 
                title="Ichabod Library" 
                vendor="My Company" 
                version="0.3" 
                description="Ichabod Library for Mobile Applications" 
                arguments="" 
                systemmodule="false" 
                runonstartup="false" 
                startuptier="7" 
                ribbonposition="0">
            </jdp>

            <src>
                <fileset dir=".">
                    <include name="src/**/*.java" />
                    <!-- <include name="resource/**/*.*" /> -->
                </fileset>
            </src>
        </rapc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: To confirm- "Ichabod" is an externally build COD file which you're manually deploying to the simulator directory via the bb-ant-tasks script.  When deploying to 4.5.0.21 the library module is found and working; but it is not found (preventing the app from running) in the updated version 4.5.0.28?

Comment: Hi Marc:

Yes, that is correct.  I have verified that the .cod file for Ichabod is in both directories, but only the simulator version '21' works, whereas the simulator version '28' shows neither the module in the Settings->Advanced Options->Applications->Modules, nor does it allow me to run my application (which depends on the library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears, after removing the 4.5.0.28 plugin from Eclipse and reinstalling it, that this was what was causing my troubles.  I don't know whether this has anything to do with it, but I also removed the JDE 4.5.0 library (which was correctly set at version 28) from the build path of the Ichabod project and replaced it with the same JDE.

After all of this nonsense, my library now shows up in the simulator. Thanks to all who looked at this.  Hopefully this will help someone else.